# How to make predicate repeat N number of times in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I have a number of lists containing letters and I have written a predicate that checks whether or not there are duplicates present in one of these given lists:

```
noDuplicates([]).
noDuplicates([H|T]):-
  not(member(H, T)),
  noDuplicates(T).
```

I have 10 lists and I want to know if there are no duplicates in any of them, so I made them into sublists of one big list, something like:

```
[[A,B,C], [C,A,D], [E,F,G]...]]
```

(So there can be duplicates in the big list, but not the individual sublists).

I get that I have to do the duplicates test 10 times; once for every sublist, but how do I write this in Prolog? I could probably write it down 10 times, but my guess is I can use recursion to make prolog repeat itself until all sublists have been checked.

So basically: I want this predicate to repeat itself N times, until N is 10. I'm really struggling with it though. Does anyone have any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 4):

Let us **generalize** the question as follows:

You have a predicate `p/1` that expresses what you want for a *single* list.

Thus, to *lift* this definition to a *list* of such lists, you can define a predicates `ps/1` as follows:

```
ps([]).
ps([L|Ls]) :-
        p(L),
        ps(Ls).
```

Every time you see this pattern, you can use `maplist/2`. That is, the above is *equivalent* to:

```
ps(Ls) :- maplist(p, Ls).
```

The goal `maplist(p, Ls)` is true **iff** `p` holds for each element `L` of `Ls`.

Note that it will limit your understanding of Prolog if you think in terms of "looping" and "repeating". These are *imperative* notions and only make sense when the list is already fully instantiated. However, from Prolog, we expect more than that: We expect a full-fledged relation to also **generate** lists for which the relation holds. And in such cases, there is nothing to "repeat" yet: We start from nothing, and ask Prolog what solutions there are *in general*.

Thus, think in terms of *describing* when the relation `ps/1` holds for lists of lists:

1. It holds for the empty list `[]`.
2. It holds for the list `[L|Ls]` *if* our initial predicate (`p/1`) holds for `L`, *and* `ps/1` holds for the remaining list `Ls`.

This *declarative* reading is applicable in all directions, no matter how many list elements are already instantiated, if any. It works for 10 lists just as well as for zero and 50.